# JIRA trigger a workflow transition via REST

Tags: rest, jira, issue-tracking

I want to trigger my test issue's current status, for example A to B via Rest call. 
I've searched on the web and come across Atlassian Documentation. What it says:

->You must use POST method.

->You must define transition id in rest call body. Like following:

```
  {
    "update": {
        "comment": [
            {
                "add": {
                    "body": "Aok was here"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "transitions": {
        "id": "471"
    }
}
```

->You must construct an url like: http://test/jira/rest/api/latest/issue/{ISSUE-KEY}/transitions

When i test above with post-man, i get nothing but a white page response body.

What may be wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone who faces this problem, here is the solution:

You need to make http request with Content-Type:application/json in header.